# Optimize MySQL SELECT containing multiple joined datetime columns

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have this query which returns what I want.

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.cust_id 
  FROM tbCustomers AS c 
  JOIN tbOrders AS o 
    ON o.order_custid = c.cust_id 
  JOIN tbPayments AS p 
    ON p.pay_custid = c.cust_id 
 WHERE (
         DATE(o.order_date) > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -14 DAY)
     AND o.order_status = '3' 
     AND o.order_exported = '0'
       ) 
    OR (
         DATE(p.pay_date) > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -14 DAY) 
     AND p.pay_exported = '0'
       )
```

However it is (relatively) slow to execute and I'd like to find a way to speed it up.
Can anyone give me a few pointers?

EDIT:

EXPLAIN AND CREATE as requested

EXPLAIN:

[image]
(with db name removed)

CREATE(S):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbCustomers` (
`cust_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cust_roundid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cust_email` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cust_pass` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cust_firstname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `cust_surname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `cust_address1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `cust_address2` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cust_town` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cust_county` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cust_postcode` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `cust_phone` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cust_evephone` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cust_delpointid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cust_notes` text NOT NULL,
  `cust_delnotes` text,
  `cust_delorder` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cust_likes` text,
  `cust_dislikes` text,
  `cust_active` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `cust_auth` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `cust_newsletter` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `cust_rep` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cust_join` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `cust_howheard` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cust_friendname` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cust_friend1staddress` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=18694 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tbOrders`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbOrders` (
`order_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `order_custid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `order_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `order_status` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `order_exported` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `order_subid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `discount_vouchers` longtext
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=310575 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tbPayments`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbPayments` (
`pay_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pay_custid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pay_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `pay_value` float NOT NULL,
  `pay_detail` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `pay_stref` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pay_nomcode` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `pay_exported` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=128264 ;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `tbCustomers`
--
ALTER TABLE `tbCustomers`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`cust_id`), ADD KEY `cust_name` (`cust_firstname`,`cust_surname`), ADD KEY `cust_email` (`cust_email`), ADD KEY `cust_newsletter` (`cust_newsletter`);

--
-- Indexes for table `tbOrders`
--
ALTER TABLE `tbOrders`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`), ADD KEY `order_custid` (`order_custid`), ADD KEY `order_date` (`order_date`), ADD KEY `order_status` (`order_status`), ADD KEY `order_exported` (`order_exported`), ADD KEY `order_subid` (`order_subid`);

--
-- Indexes for table `tbPayments`
--
ALTER TABLE `tbPayments`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`pay_id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `tbCustomers`
--
ALTER TABLE `tbCustomers`
MODIFY `cust_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=18694;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `tbOrders`
--
ALTER TABLE `tbOrders`
MODIFY `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=310575;
--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `tbPayments`
--
ALTER TABLE `tbPayments`
MODIFY `pay_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=128264;
```

Also, apologies for the incorrect column name in the where clause - fixed now

Cheers!

Comment: Just to be sure... you have set appropriate indizes on all fields you are querying, right?

Comment: Do you have any indexes ?

Comment: I have the standard primary keys, but nothing past that. I'm working with an established database and I'm uncertain what effect extra index's would have. (this is mostly my own ignorance about how indexing works rather than any db design problem)

Comment: Is `p.pay_custid` really a date?

Comment: Generally, it's a prerequisite of query performance questions that an EXPLAIN is provided, along with CREATE statements for each of the relevant tables.

Comment: If you don't have access to the script which creates the tables and if you can't modify your database but just querying it, then I don't know how you could significantly improve this query.

Comment: So, can we agree that `p` looks like the problem? What happens if you place a compound index on (pay_custid,pay_date,pay_exported)?

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed that `pay_custid` should be replaced with `pay_date` in the WHERE clause.

Rewrite the query to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.cust_id 
  FROM tbCustomers AS c 
  JOIN tbOrders AS o 
    ON o.order_custid = c.cust_id 
  JOIN tbPayments AS p 
    ON p.pay_custid = c.cust_id 
 WHERE (
         o.order_date > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 14 DAY
     AND o.order_status = 3
     AND o.order_exported = 0
       ) 
    OR (
         p.pay_date > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 14 DAY) 
     AND p.pay_exported = 0
       )
```

This allows the optimizer to use an index on `order_date` and `pay_date`, if it is wrapped in the `DATE` function the indexes cannot be used.

I'd add indexes to both date fields, but a clever composite index on each table may be more flexible.

Even better may be:

```
   SELECT DISTINCT c.cust_id 
     FROM tbCustomers AS c 
LEFT JOIN tbOrders AS o 
       ON o.order_custid = c.cust_id
      AND o.order_date > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 14 DAY
      AND o.order_status = 3
      AND o.order_exported = 0
LEFT JOIN tbPayments AS p 
       ON p.pay_custid = c.cust_id 
      AND p.pay_date > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 14 DAY) 
      AND p.pay_exported = 0
    WHERE (o.order_cust_id IS NOT NULL OR p.pay_cust_id IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: As Arth has observed, I think we can be confident that the bit about pay_custid being greater than CURDATE is wrong!

Comment: Doesn't CURDATE need ()